# Using Java spliterator with Scala

Tags: java, scala, iterator, spliterator

I am querying a database in Scala that returns a java iterable object. I call the spilterator method to create a spilterator object but I have no idea to to use the tryAdvance or forEachRemaining in Scala syntax.

The Java syntax equivalent is below and it works:

```
Spliterator<String> splitStr = nameList.spliterator();
while(splitStr.tryAdvance((n) -> System.out.println("name - " + n)));
```

Here is what I have in Scala:

```
val nameListSplit = nameList.spliterator()
while (splitStr.tryAdvance((n) -> println("name - " + n))
```

As you can see I have no idea how to to call use the tryAdvance() method in scala, same goes for the forEachRemaining method.

Comment: Why don't you just do `nameList.forEach(n -> System.out.println("name - " + n));`?

Answer (score 0):

The direct translation:

```scala
while(res4.tryAdvance { n => System.out.println("name - "+ n) }) ()
//                        ^ = not -                              ^^ unit (or {}); not ;
//                    ^ Braces instead of parens are purely style
```

The idiomatic translation:

```scala
nameList.forEach { n => println(s"name - $n") }
//       ^ foreach not iterator ^ interpolator not string +
//                      ^ println not System.out.println
//       ^ forEach in Java, foreach in Scala (pretty sure Scala had them first)
for(n <- nameList.asScala) println(s"name - $n")
// ^ for-comprehension (sugar for chained foreach, map, flatMap, filter, withFilter depending on context (generalized monad-comprehensions))
//    ^ <- as in "take n from nameList.asScala"
//                ^ convert to a Scala collection (import collection.JavaConverters._) (needed for foreach not forEach; someone should add AnyVal wrappers for that)
//                        ^ add yield here to do a (flat)map instead of foreach
```